# Make tkinter button act like ENTER

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have this script

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import commands
import CheckDatabase


root = tk.Tk()



checkbd = tk.Button(root, text="Check for new databases", command=CheckDatabase.db_download)
checkbd.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Like you see the checkbutton calls a command in CheckDatabase. Everything alright until here. In my CheckDatabase script, there is a moment where it opens a captcha in web browser and i have to click enter, after solving it, in the terminal to continue.

```py
    print('Opening captcha in browser. Press ENTER once you have solved it...')
    input()
```

Thats how i made it work in terminal.

But in tkinter i would like a button to replace that "input". How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `input()` with

```
from tkinter import messagebox
messagebox.showinfo('Waiting', 'Click ok when you have solved the captcha')
```